# IgniteCheckedException while running ignite-ssh tests

Tags: ignite

I have built Apache Ignite from source and currently running tests. The test execution was stuck at `ignite-core` module for long. Hence ran module wise tests by cd'ing to individual modules and running `mvn test`.
However facing test errors in `ignite-ssh` module as below:

```
IgniteProjectionStartStopRestartSelfTest>GridAbstractTest.access$000:140->GridAbstractTest.runTestInternal:2087->testCustomScript:498->startNod?s:1054
[ERROR] testCustomScript(org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteProjectionStartStopRestartSelfTest)  Time elapsed: 0.11 s  <<< ERROR!
org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Password or private key file must be specified.
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteProjectionStartStopRestartSelfTest.startNodes(IgniteProjectionStartStopRestartSelfTest.java:1054)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteProjectionStartStopRestartSelfTest.testCustomScript(IgniteProjectionStartStopRestartSelfTest.java:498)
**Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Password or private key file must be specified.**
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteProjectionStartStopRestartSelfTest.startNodes(IgniteProjectionStartStopRestartSelfTest.java:1054)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteProjectionStartStopRestartSelfTest.testCustomScript(IgniteProjectionStartStopRestartSelfTest.java:498)
```

Am I missing something? SSH creds need to be supplied before test?

Comment: I believe it's better not to ask questions related to development of specific products on SO - it is way to narrow. Ignite has a [developers mailing list](https://ignite.apache.org/community/resources.html) - better to ask there.

Answer (score 0):

Which version do you build from?

There is a recent update to that test done in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-9545. The new documentation seems to have a good description of the required parameters.

Comment: **Building 2.6.0.** Thanks for pointing to the issue. There are other issues like "Cannot write to directory: <ignite-home>/work/marshaller" once the ssh happens. I am subscribing to the mailing list.

Comment: Is there a place where I can get more information on tests? Are the instructions documented anywhere? or CI to look for existing failures when built from source?

Comment: @NamrataB start by writing to dev@ignite.apache.org (I've already resent your message from the user-list there), people will walk you through there.